How to get footnotes under the risk table (not in the middle of Kaplan Meier graph and risk table) in R?
I'm building a Kaplan Meier graph with a risk table and also like add a footnote. But, the footnote is coming in between the risk table and graph. I used survival, survminer and ggplot2 packages.
I used following code.
survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ surg, data = df_colon) %>%
  ggsurvfit() +   
  add_confidence_interval() +   
  add_risktable() +   
  scale_color_grey() +   
  scale_fill_grey() +   
  labs(title = "Grey Scale", caption = "FIgure1: Kaplan Meier Graph of Surgery status ")

Here, you can see that this graph I got has footnotes above the risk table:

How to get the footnote below the risk table and Kaplan Meier graph?

Under the hood ggsurvfit combines the plot and the risk table using patchwork.
The only option I have found to achieve your desired result is to first call ggsurvfit_build, then add the title and the caption using patchwork::plot_annotation:
library(ggsurvfit)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

p <- survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ surg, data = df_colon) %>%
  ggsurvfit() +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable() +
  scale_color_grey() +
  scale_fill_grey()

p |> 
  ggsurvfit_build() +
  patchwork::plot_annotation(
    title = "Grey Scale",
    caption = "FIgure1: Kaplan Meier Graph of Surgery status "
  )



Thank you so much @stefan! I'm able to replicate the results. But, the caption/footnotes is placed more towards right. How to place it towards left or center? Thanks again!
